# Combine Multiple IIS7 Rewrite Rules (Redirects) Into One

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I am using iis7's URL Rewrite module to accomplish several things:

- 301 redirect rule from non-www to www
- 301 redirects rule .info to .com (moved to the .com version of my domain)
- 301 redirects rule from an old page e.g. /page-name.asp to just /page-name

I have been able to combine the first two into one rule, and the 3rd item is it's own rule. The problem is that two 301 redirects are generated in a case of requesting a url like:

site.info/page-name.asp/

First a 301 is done to:

www.site.com/page-name.asp (e.g. www is added and .info goes to .com)

Then a second 301 is done from that to:

www.site.com/page-name

My question is:  how can I combine these so that only ONE 301 redirect occurs instead of two?  Here are the two rules as they currently sit in my web.config:

```
<rule name="SEO - 301 Redirect - .info to .com AND force WWW" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site\.info$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:http://www.site.com/{R:1}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name=".aspVersion-to-friendlyvia301" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*).asp" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer to my own question. It is a bit of a hack but accomplishes all required url transformations (e.g. trailing slash removal, non-www to www, toLowerCase, removal of default document for directories, and any other redirects necessary such as a page name change).

The problem I was talking about is actually called "chaining of 301 redirects", and the solution is presented rather elegantly, here:

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/what-every-seo-should-know-about-iis#chaining

Comment: Since externals pages may disappears before this current page, it is better to always extract and rephrase the solution from the link in your answer. (While still providing the link at least for credits.)
True, in this case, that is quite a bit of work.

Comment: Could you please share your line of codes here. That will be really helpful. I am unable to find anything which shows merging of two or more rules on the link you shared!

Comment: There is no "merging" of rules - you will just be chaining the rules, and IIS processes them all and performs a single rewrite or redirect depending on your situation.Experiment with the rules in the article and use Fiddler to monitor what is happening and you will see how it works

Answer (score 0):

This solution from previous comment:

1) Instead of **Redirect** apply **Rewrite** with additional symbol _

2) Add new rule that will catch up URL starts with _ and apply redirect

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="_{ToLower:{R:1}}" />
</rule>
<rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions  logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="_{R:1}" />
    </rule>
<rule name="Final redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(_+)(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: So is this just an alternative solution?  Can you explain why I might want to use this instead of the previous?

Comment: No, its the same solution with concrete details.