# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite: Is there a better way to rewrite / combine multiple rules

Tags: url, iis, web-config, url-rewriting

We are building a new mobile based website for an already existing website (that is used heavily by the client).

In this scenario when a user requests certain webpages on the existing web-application from a mobile device, the request for the existing web application must be Redirected to the new mobile web application.

To summarize, we have the following conditions-

1. If the web page request contains a Query String (jobId), it must be
   redirected to a mobile web page (JobDtls.aspx) used with another
   Query String parameter name (jId); but with the same query string
   value.
2. If the web page request does not contain a query string, the
   Redirection must be to the default.aspx page of the mobile web site.
3. Both the above conditions must work only if the request is through a
   mobile device.

---

For this Task, I came up with 2 different rewrite rules as described below. However, since I am new to this topic, I wanted to know if someone could optimize on this configuration; with maybe 1 Rule instead.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Mobile Entry With QueryString" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Job.aspx" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="jobid=([0-9]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="htps://{HTTP_HOST}/MWeb/mjobitem.aspx?jid={C:1}" rdirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Mobile Entry Without QueryString" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Job.aspx" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/MWeb" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: You have a typo in the first action line

Answer (score 0):

First, it does not looks like your case may benefit of any form of combination of your rules.

"Combining" redirect rules makes especially sense when you want to avoid redirects chaining. Your case is not leading to redirects chaining. See [Combine Multiple IIS7 Rewrite Rules (Redirects) Into One](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12933851/1178314) for more on this (and especialy answer link, if the answer is still not completed with the solution provided by the link). Moreover, it is not really combining rules in one, it does allow them to run and accumulates prior to performing the final resulting action.

Then, it looks like we can not have in a same rule some conditions with logicalGrouping MatchAll and others with logicalGrouping MatchAny, which would be required for combining conditions of both rules. An other way would be to elaborate a more complex regular expression matching both query string condition. But it would lead to something harder to understand, so this looks to me undesirable.

And this is just for combining conditions. You would have another trouble to tackle: actions are not the same. I do not think there is a way there to express an action handling both of your cases.